# js forward slash not printing

Tags: javascript, html, function

I want a javascript function to replace all the b's with an html `<br />` tag but it's only printing `<br>`.
Here is the function:

```
var destination = source.replace(/b/g,"<br \/>");
```

It doesn't work, is it wrong? If so, could someone please show me how to do it?

Comment: Can you maybe rephrase the question? Can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: What's only printing `<br>`? Unless you're using XHTML, there is no difference anyway.

Answer (score 3):

**Original**

There is no reason for the `\` in the string.

```
var destination = source.replace(/b/g,"<br/>");
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ATcpL/)

**Edit**

Now you gave a sample fiddle with this code

```
function gettext(){
    var input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    var value = input.replace("/b/g","<br/>");
    var output = document.getElementById("out").value = value;
}
```

Look at the replace line

```
var value = input.replace("/b/g","<br/>");
```

it is a string not a regular expression

```
"/b/g"
```

It needs to be

```
var value = input.replace(/b/g,"<br/>");
```

[jsFiddle Example with your code](http://jsfiddle.net/mVs9T/6/)

Comment: That also does not work, I get the string from an html textarea's value, could that not be a problem?

Comment: @Stuyvenstein Please create a minimal test-case and put it in the post and on jsfiddle.

Comment: I cant get it to work there, the same code that works in my browser?

Comment: You have the settings wrong on the fiddle, updated it so your code runs: http://jsfiddle.net/mVs9T/4/

Comment: Ok got it working now, you see the breaklines work but with wrong syntax, printing <br> instead of <br />

Comment: The browser debugger will not show it and there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Why is there nothing I can do about it?

Comment: The debugger does not show it, that is my point. You can not make it show it, has nothing to do with the JavaScript code.