# Javascript not writing forward slash

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following: http://jsfiddle.net/mVs9T/13/

Could someone please tell me why the output is printing

```
<br>
```

instead of:

```
<br/>
```

like here: http://f.imgtmp.com/Xjoq3.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [js forward slash not printing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641850/js-forward-slash-not-printing)

Comment: I felt I needed to rephrase it

Comment: And the same answer I told you still applies here! The browser just does not show it and there is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We added `alert(txt);` and it gave us `<br/>` - looks good to go.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because that is how chrome interprets the `<br />` tag.  It's just aesthetic; you need not worry about it.

Comment: So the actual output is <br/>? I don't know how to check this in IE and firefox

Comment: well on FF you can save the code into a file and run it, after putting in the input, select all, right click and do view selection source

Comment: Yes.  As for IE and Firefox, respectively: F12, and you need to install Firebug.  You could also just 'view source' of the page.

Comment: Ok i found as way with ff but it still shows <br> instead of <br />

Comment: Ahh crap i inserted a normal html <br/> tag and it still shows <br> so its not my js... Damn. stupid me...

Answer (score 0):

That's browser behaviour. It shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since nothing can go between a `<br>` tag the `/>` part is not necessary. This is probably why the browser doesn't display it.